# array_map for multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find a solution to using `array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $data);` on multidimensional arrays, If $data is multidimensional, php returns an error. cheers

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
$array = array( array('A' => "Hello", 'B' => "World"),
                array('A' => "Goodnight", 'B' => "Vienna")
              );

function myFunc(&$item, $key) {
    $item = mysql_real_escape_string($item);
}

array_walk_recursive($array,'myFunc');

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: unfortunately won't work if you're trying to modify the keys

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [minwork/array](https://github.com/minwork/array) to easily map any multidimensional array.

Biggest advantage of this solution over native functions is that you can map multidimensional arrays with various nesting depth also accessing their keys, for example:

```php
$array = [
    1 => [
        2 => 'a',
        3 => 'b',
        4 => [
            5 => 'c',
        ],
    ],
    'test' => 'd',
];

$callback = function ($keys, $value) {
    return implode('.', $keys) . " -> {$value}";
}

Arr::map($array, $callback, Arr::MAP_ARRAY_KEYS_ARRAY_VALUE) ->
[
    1 => [
        2 => '1.2 -> a',
        3 => '1.3 -> b',
        4 => [
            5 => '1.4.5 -> c',
        ],
    ],
    'test' => 'test -> d',
]
```

In your case you can simply apply `mysql_real_escape_string` function (without modifying input array) to every element like this (no matter how deeply each element is nested)

```php
$escapedData = Arr::map($data, function ($value) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}, Arr::MAP_ARRAY_VALUE_KEYS_LIST);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function realEscape($data){
    global $connection;
        $array=[];
  do{

    if(is_string($data)){
        $array= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data);
       break; 
    }


foreach($data as $key =>$value){
      $array[$key]=is_array($value)?realEscape($value):mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value);  
}


}while(0);
return $array;}
```

A simple solution fit anywhere. Cheers !